# split a list by increment of 2

Tags: python

I want to split a list with slide of twos:

my list

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4]
```

desired output:

```
[[1,2][3,4][5,6][3,4]]
```

But I've tried:

```
def split_list(a_list):
    ind1 = 0

    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(a_list)):
        a_list = a_list[ind1:ind1+2]
        new_list.append(a_list)
        ind1 = ind1 + 2

    return new_list
```

Comment: and what output do you get currently?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/1324033

Comment: this is the output I get currently    [[1, 2], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]